# 2,3,7 is the only triple $\geq 2$ that satisfies this property

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The property being that "taking the product of two of the numbers and adding one yields a number that is divisible by the third".

Clearly, this holds for 2,3,7 since

- $2\cdot 3 + 1 = 1\cdot 7$
- $2\cdot7 + 1 = 5\cdot 3$
- $3\cdot 7 + 1 = 11\cdot 2$

but why is this the only such triple?

This is from a (German) textbook on algebraic number theory, reviewing elementary number theory in chapter 1. Up to this point, only divisibility, the gcd and the euclidean algorithm have been introduced (no prime numbers yet). I took an elementary number theory course last semester, but I'm completely puzzled by this problem and don't know where to start. Trying to set up some equations and to manipulate them doesn't lead me anywhere.

**My solution attempt**

We can, without loss of generality, assume $2 \leq a \leq b \leq c$. From MXYMXY's answer below we have $abc|ab+bc+ca+1$ (which I'll denote (*)) and also that $a < 4$.

Let's then consider the two possibilities for $a$ in turn.

1. $a =3$: We can show that $b$ and $c$ can't both be $\geq 4$, for if they were we would have $$\frac{3}{c}+1+\frac{3}{b}+\frac{1}{bc} \leq \frac{3}{4}+1+\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{16} < 3 \Leftrightarrow 3b + bc + 3c + 1 < 3bc,$$
   but from (*) we have $3bc|3b+bc+3c+1$, which is a contradiction.

   It follows that $b = 3$ and then we have $ab+1=10$, so $c|10$. Hence $c = 5$ or $c = 10$, but $a = 3$ divides neither $3\cdot5 + 1 = 16$ nor $3\cdot10 + 1 = 31$. Thus, this case is impossible.
2. $a = 2$. We will show that $b$ and $c$ can't be both $\geq 5$. Otherwise we'd have $$\frac{2}{c}+1+\frac{2}{b}+\frac{1}{bc} \leq \frac{2}{5}+1+\frac{2}{5}+\frac{1}{25} < 2 \Leftrightarrow 2b + bc + 2c + 1 < 2bc,$$ but from (*) we have that $2bc|2b+bc+2c+1$, which is a contradiction. This implies that $2 \leq b < 5$. Let's consider the different cases for $b$:

   1. $b=4$: Then we have $ab+1=9$, so $c|9$, i.e. $c = 9$. But $a = 2$ does not divide $4\cdot 9 + 1 = 37$, so this is a contradiction.
   2. $b=2$: Then $ab+1=5$, so $c|5$, i.e. $c = 5$. But $a = 2$ does not divide $2\cdot 5 + 1 = 11$, so we also have a contradiction.

The only case left is where $a = 2, b = 3$. Then, we have $ab+1=7$, so $c|7$. Hence, $c=7$.

Hence, either $2,3,7$ is the only solution or there is none. That it is indeed a solution was verified above.

Comment: This seems to imply that $abc|ab+bc+ca+1$, and I think we can use inequalities..

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti what do you mean by "cyclic ones"?

Comment: What about $(1,1,1)$ and $(1,2,3)$ as $1 \times 2 +1 = 3$, $1 \times 3 +1 = 4$ and $2 \times 3 +1=7$?

Comment: @Hetebrij you're right. I missed the condition that the numbers have to be $\geq 2$.

Comment: I think you are mistaken: In your first case, where $a=3$, $b=3$, this implies $9c|10+6c$, does not seem to imply $c=10k$ (or if it does, that part is a bit unclear). It would be slightly more simple to note that $9c \ge 10+6c$, which implies $c=3$.

Comment: @MXYMXY Yes, of course. It was silly. $c|10$ does not imply $c = 10x$ (indeed, it's the other way around, $10c = x$). Must have got carried away in the heat of doing computations. I changed my answer, hopefully it's correct now.

Comment: @Fryie It seems fine now.

Comment: @MXYMXY Thanks. If I may ask, would you say this is a difficult question? Because I'm in my second year now and I wouldn't have gotten anywhere without your hint.

Comment: @Fryie I hope you don't mind me being too honest, but in a contest math perspective, this is a simple question (this strategy is well known). A similar question was in my high-school textbook.  That said, if you have never seen this method before, it is actually quite difficult. I might mention that only a year before, I would not have been able to answer the question.

Comment: I don't mind honesty at all, but then again I'm not interested in "contest" mathematics so much as in being able to do "enough computations" to be able to follow along the more interesting topics (because computation is not so "interesting" to me, it's just that I want to be able to do what's required). I didn't do stuff like that in high school, but I went to a liberal arts college. :) The trick with using fractions in order to prove inequalities will probably turn out to be useful in the future, so thanks for that.

Comment: I'm sorry, what I recommended seems to be the wrong course of action. You should have added it as an another answer. I am terribly sorry.

Comment: why, what's the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $a|bc+1$, $b|ca+1$, $c|ab+1$, multiplying these together gives us that $$abc|ab+bc+ca+1$$

Note that $$a,b,c \ge 4 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{abc}<1 \Leftrightarrow abc>ab+bc+ca+1$$

This gives us that one of $a,b,c$ must be smaller than $4$.

I think you can continue to divide cases from here. It requires slightly complicatd calculations, but not very.

Comment: I think I'm missing something - multiplying the terms together just gives me $abc|(bc+1)(ca+1)(ab+1)$. How do I get from here to $abc|ab + bc + ca + 1$?

Comment: That gives us $abc|(abc)^2+abc(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca+1$.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll see if I can work from there. I'm still a bit uneasy with inequalities, so it'll probably take some practice.

Comment: I think I came up with a working proof based on your idea, but I'd like to have it double checked. Should I post it as an answer (it will be too long for the comments section)?

Comment: @Fryie Why don't you edit it in in your question?

Comment: I edited my question with my solution attempt based on your idea. Would be nice if you could have a look at it.

Comment: Hi @S.C.B., in your comment from Mar 3, what happened to the first two terms, before the $ab$ +$bc$ + ... ?

Comment: Since $abc$ unconditionally divides the terms before it, they were no longer necessary. It is like how if $3$ divides $3k+a$, we can say $3$ divides $a$.

Comment: That is because my inequality was only a rough estimate.

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently $a$ divides $bc+1$ and cyclic ones. In particular, they are pairwise coprime. Then $abc$ divides $\prod_{\mathrm{cyc}}(ab+1)$, implying that $abc$ divides $1+\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}ab$. Suppose wlog $a>b>c\ge 2$. If $c\ge 3$ then 
$$
3ab \le abc \le 1+\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}}ab\le 1+(ab-1)+(ab-1)+ab<3ab,
$$
which is impossible. Then $c$ has to be $2$. Then conditions are (i) $2\mid ab+1$ (i.e., $a$ and $b$ are odd), (ii) $a\mid 2b+1$ and (iii) $b\mid 2a+1$. Hence 
$$
b\le 2a+1 \le 2(2b+1)+1 \implies \frac{2a+1}{b} \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}.
$$
The ratio between odd numbers has to be odd, hence [$2a+1=3b$ or $5b$] and [$2b+1=a$ or $3a$]. Therefore we find the above unique solution $(2,3,7)$.

Comment: So I think your answer is probably slightly "too fast" for me. I have a couple of questions. 1. by $\prod_{cyc} ab + 1$ do you mean $ab + bc + ac + 1$? Because I haven't seen this notation (nor the term "cyclic ones").

Comment: 2. How do you get the inequality $1 + \sum_{cyc} ab \leq 1 + (ab - 1) + (ab - 1) + ab$?

Comment: 3. Why is $2a + 1 = b$ or $2b + 1 = 5a$ impossible in your second-to-last sentence? And how do you derive the unique solution from that?